# Rails: How to track users last logged in ip address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would I go about tracking the last IP address of a signed in user not the current as I'm sure that can be achieved by

```
@ip = request.remote_ip
```

Comment: save it in the database, so next time you can compare! that doesn't look like a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the current user's IP address is how you will have access to the IP address of the last user. If for every session you recorded the IP address of the person logged in, you will eventually have a record of all the users that have ever logged in. To get the last user's IP address, just query for the last record that was added.

A simple solution is to create a table with one column and add to it as you go.

Here is what the migration file is going to look like.

```
class CreateUserIp < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_ip do |t|
      t.string :ip_address

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Be sure to run the migration from the terminal

```
rails db:migrate
```

Now, every time a user logs in, for every session you can insert the current IP address into the table.

```
UserIp.create(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
```

Now you can retrieve the latest record like so,

```
last_users_ip = UserIp.order(created_at: :asc).reverse_order.limit(10).reverse.first
```

There you go!

Answer (score 1):

Use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem for authentication (if not familiar with yet). It offers [IP tracking](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable) out of the box

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `request.remote_ip` that's simple and it works.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      def remote_ip
        if request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'
          # Hard coded remote address
          '123.45.67.89'
        else
          request.remote_ip
        end
      end
    end

    class MyController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @client_ip = remote_ip()
      end
    end
```

When you visit a site locally you're coming from the local IP address, ie 127.0.0.1.

What you're doing is the correct way to the visitors IP address, and the result you're seeing is as expected.

You want to use

```
@ip = request.remote_ip
```

because that takes into account most cases of reverse proxies and other situations you might encounter where `request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']` might be nil or the address of the local proxy.

Comment: Yes but this wouldn't grab the ip address the logged in user used prior to his current session

Comment: @RushRed I have edited my answer can you check with that