# How to get current_sign_in_ip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails for the backend and react for the frontend. I am using rails api only.

I would like to store the `current_sign_in_ip` for every user. I am not using devise. How can I achive it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails: How to track users last logged in ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629226/rails-how-to-track-users-last-logged-in-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get IP in a controller by calling `request.remote_ip`

Answer (score 1):

This will work as well.

```
request.ip
```

> EDIT

`request.ip` is ip detection method provided by `Rack::Request`. It looks at the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header and picks the last one from the list.

[source](https://apidock.com/rails/Rack/Request/ip)

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. This would make it more useful in the long run.

Comment: @tiagoperes Thanks for suggestion. I have edited my answer. if you still feel description is too sort then feel free to update it.

Comment: Also, don't forget the GDPR requirements saving the IP address might entail. Probably worth looking into since this is another piece of personal identifying information you're collecting.

Answer (score 1):

> request.remote_ip

`request.remote_ip` is an interpretation of all the available IP address information and it will make a best-guess. If you access the variables directly you assume responsibility for testing them in the correct precedence order. Proxies introduce a number of headers that create environment variables with different names.